# Переделать SQL под HQL или Criteria

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, hql

Есть запрос

```
SELECT ID, BOOK_TITLE, BOOK_AUTHOR, 
born FROM bookmanager.book  WHERE born <= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 10 year)
```

не могу переделать под HQL
или же заставить этот часть кода работать

```
@Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Book> old1() {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        List<Book> bookList1 = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT ID, BOOK_TITLE, BOOK_AUTHOR, born FROM bookmanager.book  WHERE born <= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 10 year))").list();
  return bookList1;
    }
```

Запрос не работает. Буду признателен в помощи с запросом или же с кодом

Comment: Как именно он не работает? Кидает ошибку? Если да - то какую?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб есть вывод в таблицу по списку. Через запрос ничего не выводит

Answer (score 2):

```
Date date_add(Date date, int field, int amount) {
  Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
  c.setTime(date);
  c.add(field, amount);
  return c.getTime();
}

Date newDate = date_add(new Date(), Calendar.YEAR, -10);
Query query = session.createQuery("from Book b where b.born <= :newDate");
query.setParameter("newDate", newDate);
List<Book> bookList1 = query.list();
```

Comment: Ничего не поменялось. Результат тот же. Есть еще варинаты?

Comment: Message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: INTERVAL near line 1, column 81 [from net.proselyte.bookmanager.model.Book b where b.born <= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 10 year))]

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Comment: @Jackson750 такая ошибка не может произойти если использовать код из ответа